# To find the integration over the given region of complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate the integral $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{e^z-1} \, dz$ over C where C is circle with centre 2i and radius 4.

I guess I have to use Cauchy Integral theorem here. I can find the point of singularities by equating $e^z-1=0$ Then use the Cauchy theorem. Am I going right? I need some help to evaluate this integral

Comment: It seems you have an idea, what happens if you actually try to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the residue at zero:

$$e^z-1=z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\ldots\implies\frac1{e^z-1}=\frac1{z\left(1+\frac z2+\frac{z^2}6+\ldots\right)}\stackrel{(*)}=$$

$$\frac1z\left(1-\frac z2+\frac{z^2}4-\ldots\right)=\frac1z-\frac12+\ldots$$

The equality $\;(*)\;$ is justified because we work with $\;z\;$ such that $\;|z|\;$ is very close to zero, and thus

$$\oint_C\frac{dz}{e^z-1}=1\cdot2\pi i=2\pi i$$

You can also calculate the residue by deducing first that it is a simple pole, and then:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\;z\,f(z)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac z{e^z-1}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac1{e^z}=1$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{z^2}{6}$ in the second line?

Comment: @Ramanujan In that expression I only took $\;1+\frac z2\;$ as meaningful terms (as $\;|z|\;$ is close to zero), and thus what is written NOW (I corrected) in the second line.